# What is the python version of this Powershell command?

Tags: python, powershell

Looking to convert this powershell code into python:

```
$secretArgs = @{
    fileName = "test.pem"
    fileAttachment = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\brian\13568-test.txt")
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

*Update:
I am trying this code to get a similar result:

```
import json

test_file = open("test.txt", "rb")
test_file_name = "test.txt"

body = {"filename":test_file_name,"fileattachment":test_file}
print(body)
data = json.dumps(body)
print(data)
```

The goal to find a pythonic method for this powershell snippet:

```
    $endpoint ="$destinationapi/secrets/$fileSecretId/fields/$fileFieldToUpdate"
    echo $endpoint
    
    $secretArgs = @{
        fileName = "test.pem"
        fileAttachment = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\brian\13568-test.txt")
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    
    $response = $null
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $endpoint -Headers $destinationheaders -Body $secretArgs -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: What do you think that PowerShell command even does?

Comment: creates a json object. The problem is the [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes() pieces which produces a byte array. I am not finding a way to do this in python in order to create a json object. When trying to do it with open(test.txt, 'rb') produces an error.

Comment: Post your python code and the error it generates. There really isn't any such thing as a "json object", at least not in python. json is a serialization format that creates python objects. `data = json.load(open(r"C:\brian\13568-test.txt"))` may do the trick.

Comment: The PowerShell command as provided doesn't really do anything specific - perhaps that changes depending on the contents of the files referenced, but it seems like it has problems itself. Regardless, there's no Python code here and what you added in the comments (please update your question instead) is syntactically incorrect Python. Reading a file as a binary is trivial in Python, but it's unclear how that's supposed lead to a JSON object - what are the contents of the file? And what do you expect the JSON object to contain after the operation? Are you after a Python dictionary, or list?

Comment: Here is an example output of the powershell: 
{
    "fileName":  "test.pem",
    "fileAttachment":  [
                           98,
                           108,
                           97,
                           104,
                           32,
                           98,
                           108,
                           97,
                           104,
                           32,
                           98,
                           108,
                           97,
                           104
                       ]
}

Comment: I need to make a json object with the byte array of the file to add it to a "Put" request for an api call. The goal is to upload a file to a server.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

secretArgs = {"fileName": "test.pem"}

with open("test.pem", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
raw_bytes = list(bytearray(data, "utf-8"))
secretArgs["fileAttachment"] = list(bytes(raw_bytes))
print(json.dumps(secretArgs))
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small test file to see what the powershell command did exactly.

```
PS C:\> cat C:\temp\13568-test.txt
blah blah blah
PS C:\> $secretArgs = @{
>>     fileName = "test.pem"
>>     fileAttachment = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:/temp/13568-test.txt")
>> } | ConvertTo-Json
PS C:\> echo $secretArgs
{
    "fileName":  "test.pem",
    "fileAttachment":  [
                           98,
                           108,
                           97,
                           104,
                           32,
                           98,
                           108,
                           97,
                           104,
                           32,
                           98,
                           108,
                           97,
                           104
                       ]
}
PS C:\>
```

To reproduce this in Python it seems to be:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

test_file = Path("C:/temp/13568-test.txt")

content = {"fileName": "test.pem",
           "fileAttachment": list(test_file.read_bytes())}

secret_args = json.dumps(content, indent=4)

print(secret_args)
```

Which gave the following output:

```
{
    "fileName": "test.pem",
    "fileAttachment": [
        98,
        108,
        97,
        104,
        32,
        98,
        108,
        97,
        104,
        32,
        98,
        108,
        97,
        104
    ]
}
```